# Download a File in the client's downloads folder (NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, download, webclient

I have a project in Node where I put a Youtube video URL and then I download it. Now it works, but I have the next problem: when I download a video from another PC (in the same LAN), the video goes to the main PCs downloads folder. For example, i deploy the app in my main pc (PC1), and then I download a video from PC2 (another that is in the same LAN that PC1), this video is downloaded in PC1s downloads folder. This is part of my code:

```
    const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router(); //EL ENCARGADO DE CREAR LAS RUTAS
//const downloadsFolder = require('downloads-folder');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs')
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');

router.post('/video-url-upload', async (req, res)=>{
    var downloadFolder = path.join(process.env.USERPROFILE, "/Downloads/");
    console.log(downloadFolder);
    //console.log(downloadsFolder());
 
    const url = req.body.urlsubida;
    
    let nombre = await (await ytdl.getInfo(url)).videoDetails.title;
    const nombre_archivo = nombre + '.mp4';
    console.log(nombre_archivo);
    ytdl(url).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(downloadFolder + nombre_archivo));

    res.send('video.mp4');
})

module.exports = router;
```

I want the video storage in PC2 downloads folder, but i don't know how I can do it.

Comment: Is the download folder shared among LAN networks? Or you just can't see it on PC2?

Comment: I can't see it in pc2

Comment: Have you tried it on mobile connecting with the same network? I'm not sure what could be the problem.

Comment: Yes but its the same...

Comment: If think you have a xy problem here. You cand download the youtube video to your server and store then the file on the clients download folder. The only possible solution would be to download the file directly onto the client. (or proxy it through your app)

Comment: how can i download a file directly onto the client?